# fit multiple images on background image using imagemagick

Tags: background, imagemagick

I am trying to use image magic to do the following:

1. I have pdf with multiple pages, I want to convert them into JPG.
2. I have a background image with fixed width and height which will work as a container.
3. I want to place each of the converted JPGs alone on the background image and fit it on the background image with stretching and keeping the image proportion, so the background image will fill the empty space around it.
4. I want to save the result image as JPG in two different specific sizes.

[image: http://s23.postimg.org/hjsk7ws3v/image.jpg]

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/72ckiwosr/image.jpg]

How could I do that?

Comment: What are all the stars for? And what have you tried?